# What's the music played during the final battle of Tokyo Ghoul √A episode 4?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

What's the name of the song or the artist that sings in the final battle of episode 4 of *Tokyo Ghoul √A*, when Kaneki is battling Shachi?

Comment: [The Tokyo Ghoul OST doesn't come out until March 25, 2015](http://vgmdb.net/album/50263), so you'll probably have to wait until then to find out what it's called.

Answer (score 3):

The song used is track 10: **Wanderers** (vocal by Luschka) from disc 2 of the [Tokyo Ghoul Original Soundtrack](http://vgmdb.net/album/50263).